# I cant find a way to print my array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Hey stackoverflow people, can you help me with this script. I dont know how to print this type of array with javascript for. Here is how my array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [13] => John Freeman
    [14] => Jim Golish
    [36] => Tim Morgan
    [38] => Lusy Jay
)
```

And here is my javascript:

```
  var myObject = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);  // Received the data 

    var str="<table width='50%'  align=center><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#ffff00'>ID</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#ffff00'>Name</th></tr>";
  for(i=0;i<myObject.data.length;i++)
  { 
    str = str + "<tr><td>" + myObject.data[i] + " </td><td>"+ myObject.data[i] + "</a></td></tr>"
  }
```

Here is how JSON encode look like:

```
{"data":{"13":"John Freeman","14":"Jim Golish","36":"Tim Morgan","38"
:"Lusy Jay"}}
```

How to print my type of array  with that javascript `for(i=0;i<myObject.data.length;i++)`?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Updated

Comment: That json string is equates to an object with 4 properties of `myobject.13`, `myobject.14`, `myobject.36` , `myobject.38`. **Show us how you build that json string**

Comment: Please define "print".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dealing with an object, not an *array*, so go with `for in`

```js
var data = {"data":{"13":"John Freeman","14":"Jim Golish","36":"Tim Morgan","38"
:"Lusy Jay"}} ;

for(var key in data.data){
  console.log(key);
  console.log(data.data[key]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not a javascript array, your data variable is a javascript object, you should use

```
 for(var i in myObject.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for(i=0;i<Object.keys(myObject.data).length;i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to print it to the console you can just use

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 2));
```

Which will pretty print your object.

Or did you want to display it as html in the page?

Answer (score 1):

you need to this format
Array
(
    '13' => John Freeman
    '14'=> Jim Golish
...
)

and make a print with a for

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
var data = {"data":{"13":"John Freeman","14":"Jim Golish","36":"Tim Morgan","38":"Lusy Jay"}} ;


 var str="<table width='50%'  align=center><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#ffff00'>ID</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#ffff00'>Name</th></tr>";
  for(var key in data.data)
  { 
    str = str + "<tr><td>" + key + " </td><td>"+ data.data[key] + "</a></td></tr>";
  }
document.write(str);
```